# Cuantas veces se repite un elemento de una tabla en otra? C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp

Buen día tengo dos tablas una que se llama software y otra llamada nombreSoftware

```
nombreSoftware    software

id nombre        id   nombreSoftware_id
1  VS code       1     1
2  Office        2     1
3  W10           3     1
                 4     2
```

Necesito saber cuantas veces se repiten los elementos nombreSoftware_id

utilice el siguiente código en LINQ

```
var Repeticiones = db.Eq_tblSoftware
                   .GroupBy(p => p.Eq_tblNombresSoftware.id)
                   .Select(g => new { Id_nom = g.Key, Repeticiones = g.Count()});
```

y funciona bien solo que por ejemplo el elemento con id 3 de la tabla nombreSoftware no aparece y me gustaria que apareciera como en Repeticiones diciendo se repite 0 veces

salida de Repeticiones:

```
Id_nom   Repeticiones 
1           3
2           1
```

Comment: quieres que aparezca el nombre de la tabla que se repite, correcto?

Comment: el id con el que esta asociado en este caso comparten nombreSoftware_id, en pocas palabras saber cuantas veces aparece el nombreSoftware.id en software.nombreSoftware_id, actualmente ya lo hace pero no puedo traer los que se repiten cero veces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hagámoslo paso a paso para no complicarnos:

```
var query1 = db.Eq_tblNombreSoftware.Select(x => x.id).ToList();
var query2 = db.Eq_tblSoftware.Select(x => x.nombreSoftware_id).ToList();    
var query3 = query1.Except(query2).ToList();
```

Hasta aquí lo que hacemos es guardar en la **variable query1** una lista con los **id** de la **tabla Eq_tblNombreSoftware** y guardar en la **variable query2** una lista con los **nombreSoftware_id** de la tabla **Eq_tblSoftware**. Posteriormente en la **variable query3** usamos el **operador de conjuntos Except** para obtener los elementos que se encuentran en la lista almacenada en la **variable query1** que no se encuentran en la lista almacenada en la **variable query2**, en tu caso obtendríamos una lista con solamente el número **3**, ya que este se encuentra en la primera lista pero no en la segunda.

Posteriormente haríamos:

```
var query4 = (from var x in query3
              select new {
                           Id_nom = x,
                           Repeticiones = 0
                         }).ToList();
```

En la **variable query4** obtendríamos una lista de **objetos anónimos** donde cada objeto tendría dos propiedades: **Id_nom** y **Repeticiones**(que por defecto se iguala a **0**, ya que no existe en el agrupamiento previamente creado por ti), por tanto ya en la **variable query4** tendríamos todos los elementos que se repiten **0** veces.

Ahora podríamos hacer:

```
var query5 = Repeticiones.ToList().Union(query4).ToList();
```

Utilizamos el **operador de conjuntos Union** para unir los resultados obtenidos previamente por ti y guardados en la **variable Repeticiones** con los resultados obtenidos en la **variable query4**.

Comment: Muchas gracias es lo que necesitaba !!! y sobre todo gracias por la explicación me sirvo mucho!